# Sluggish UITableView scrolling even after reload

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView which uses reuseCellIdentifier and includes images (downloaded asynchronously using UIImageView+AFNetworking.h); as can be expected it get sluggish after scrolling for a while and when the table gets long. I also store the data for each cell downloaded from the internet in a `NSMutableArray *_collection`, so I won't keep redownloading again every time a cell comes back into view.

My problem is that after I completely refresh the table using the following method, the scrolling is still very sluggish. The only way to make it loads smooth again is to quit the app and reopen it. I don't understand why the scrolling is still sluggish after reloading... I am using ARC and I did profile for leaks and don't see any when I reload the table..

```
-(void)refreshTable:(id)sender{
  [_collection removeAllObjects];
  _collection = nil;

  AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_baseURL]];
  [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:_path parameters:nil];
  AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation ...etc...
```

Going one step further, I also tried even removing the tableview on refresh as follows, but it doesn't help either...

```
-(void)refreshTable:(id)sender{
  [_tableView removeFromSuperView];
  _tableView = nil;
  _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
  [_tableView setDelegate:self];
  [_tableView setDataSource:self];
  [_tableView setRowHeight:kRowHeight];
  [_tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [_tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [_tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
  [self.view addSubview:_tableView];

  [_collection removeAllObjects];
  _collection = nil;

  AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_baseURL]];
  [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:_path parameters:nil];
  AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation ...etc...
```

What might be the reason why the scrolling is still sluggish after I refresh the table? thanks!

EDIT

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellId];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (CustomCell*)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [self populate:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self loadImageForCell:cell];
    return cell;
}

- (void) populate:(UITableViewCell*)customCell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)customCell;

    if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        [cell.background setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CellBgYellow"]];
    } else {
        [cell.background setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CellBgOrange"]];
    }

    DataObject* thisDataObject = [_collection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.dataObject = thisDataObject;
    cell.titleLabel.text = [thisDataObject objectForKey:kCellTitle];
    cell.timestampLabel.text = [thisDataObject objectForKey:kCellTimestamp];
}

- (void) loadImageForCell:(CustomCell*)cell
{
    [cell.profilePic setImage:nil];
    NSString* profilePicURL = [cell.dataObject objectForKey:kCellProfilePicURL];    
    NSString* URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kBaseURL, profilePicURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *profilePicRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:URL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [profilePicRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];    
    [cell.profilePic setImageWithURLRequest:profilePicRequest
                           placeholderImage:nil
                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                                    }
                                    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                        NSLog(@"loadimageforcell error (%d): %@",error.code,error.localizedDescription);
                                    }];

    [cell.painting setImage:nil];
    NSString* paintingURL = [cell.dataObject objectForKey:kCellPaintingURL];
    URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kBaseURL, paintingURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *paintingRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:URL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [paintingRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [cell.spinner startAnimating];
    [cell.painting setImageWithURLRequest:paintingRequest
                           placeholderImage:nil
                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                                        [cell.spinner stopAnimating];
                                        [cell.spinner removeFromSuperview];
                                    }
                                    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                        NSLog(@"loadimageforcell error (%d): %@",error.code,error.localizedDescription);
                                        [cell.spinner stopAnimating];
                                        [cell.spinner removeFromSuperview];
                                    }];
}
```

Comment: Please show your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 1):

The problems are 2:

1. The call to make an image request will take up some cpu %
2. The image decoding will take another cpu %

Depending on the image size, you would have to do various things.
The easiest and more obvious solution, is to just decompress the image in another thread.
This way your main thread will not be blocked and your scroll performance should gain a decent boost.

Here is a snippet of code to get you going:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^(void) {
                    UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgFilePath];
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
                        cellImageView.image = cellImage;
                    } );
                });
```

As you can see, the UIImage is being generated in a background thread and as soon as we have the image decoded, we assign it to the cell.

In the above example, images are precached, and the imgFilePath is the path to the docments directory where the image is cached.

You could continue to improve the performance, with various other things, as with using the ABTableView cell subclass by Loren Brichter and draw the image using Core Graphics (also improves performance a lot).
Finally if the image is huge, you could set the entire cell to be a subclass of the CATiledLayer class, so that drawing of the image is also done in a background thread by the system...

Comment: thanks for this. My images are about 40k each, is that worth doing CATiledLayerClass. I have been looking at ABTableView cell, but since different parts of the cell will respond to touches differently (i.e. tapping on the username will call a different method than tapping on the picture), I am not sure how easy to follow the drawRect route.

Comment: also, quick question on the snippet you provide, that assumes the image is saved somewhere locally right? That would not work for my case where I download the images off the internet, or am I missing something? thanks again

Comment: To answer your questions: 1. You can use drawRect method and respond to different touches in the cell, by subclassing the `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method

Based on the location of the touch you could capture the area that was tapped (username, etc).
If that doesn't suit you, you can add the buttons to the cell's contentview regularly and do the drawing in the drawRect method for the large picture. 

2. The snippet I provided is for a class that has downloaded the images from the internet to the device and cached them, so it would work for you too...

Comment: thanks that's very useful information! just another follow up question. I am currently pointing to the downloaded UIImages directly in my `dataObject` (subclass of `NSDictionary`, one for each indexPath) which are then stored in the `_collection` array. Would i see better performance if I save the images locally like you do instead and load them up every time the cell comes into view? (i.e. would your `dispatch_async` be faster than `[cell.picture setImage:[[_collection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"kUIImage"]];`?

Comment: Definitely yes. AfNetworking should actually have caching abilities, I'm pretty sure, so everything should be done very easy.
What I'm doing in my app, is that for every cell I keep the image URL path, and then grab the cached image from the URL path from ASIHTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Don't load your images inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. That will just kill your scrolling.

To quickly fix your issue, only load images if the tableview is not scrolling, completely stopped.

Better way is to re think your design. By using Network Queues and lazy loading images is the way to go.

Check the apple demo of Lazy TableView : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

This taught me so much, and by using ASIHTTPRequest like you are, you can even make this more simple. But look at the code, it is well commented and easy to understand

** Update since you are using afnetwork

Do this f.ex. inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSURLRequest *imagerequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/image.png"]];
AFImageRequestOperation *op = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:imagerequest success:^(UIImage *image) {
    cell.imageview.image = image;
}];
```

Comment: thanks, let me try this and let you know the result. 

That said, this doesn't really explain why the scrolling still remain sluggish after I reload the table? could there still be a problem somewhere?

Comment: He is actually using AFNetworking and not the ASIHTTPRequest :)

Comment: When you change the data, all you need to do is call [myTableView reloadData];, everything else is too much. Since you are using AFNetworking, they have an awesome class, AFImageRequestOperation.h, which would totally solve your problem.

Comment: I have updated my answer. This is how I do things if I don't directly draw my own cells in drawrect, smooth as butter